# Dragon RTL8125BG C-states

Tags: realtek, powertop

Has anyone had success with C-states in powertop on the RTL8125?
I try to use it with Unraid 6.11.5/Ubuntu 22.04 but only on the Realtek NIC I can't get past C3.

[image]

Comment: Support for that version went EOL in Jan. 2022 and is off topic on this site.

Comment: Sorry 22.04!! :)